# How to pass a function as parameter in C++

Tags: c++

I have 2 basic functions differ about type of parameter but code in these most of the same. Because i do not want to repeat code so i do:

```
bool func(std::string x)
{
    if(x=="true")
        return true;
    return false;
}

bool func(int x)
{
    if(x!=-1)
        return true;
    return false;
}
bool fun( auto x,bool (*f)(auto ))
{
    return (*f)(x);
};
```

I have used `auto` keyword to be compatible with both functions, but it has something wrong so I need your supports.

Comment: a side comment: `if (x) return true; return false;` can always be replaced with `return (x);`

Comment: That's a slightly bizarre mix of templates and raw function pointers.

Comment: @Jaime assuming the function is declared to return `bool`

Comment: @M.M yes, I am talking about return bool

Answer (score 5):

You can use templates to implement `fun`:

```
template<typename T>
bool fun(T x, bool (*f)(T)) {
    return f(x);
}
```

But while you're at it, you can also make `fun` a bit more generic. This way it also works with objects with a custom `()` operator (e.g. `std::function`, lambdas, ...):

```
template<typename T, typename F>
bool fun(T x, F f) {
    return f(x);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use auto in function declaration, instead try to use templates something like this

```
bool func(std::string x)
{
    if(x=="true")
        return true;

    return false;
}


bool func(int x)
{
    if(x!=-1)
        return true;

    return false;
}

template<typename T>
bool fun(T x,bool (*f)(T))
{
    return (*f)(x);
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::string str = "Test";
    fun(str, func);

    int x = 2;
    fun(x, func);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Maybe `std::cout << (fun(str, func) ? "true" : "false") << '\n';` and the same for `x` to provide a bit of additional feedback on the operation?

Comment: "You cannot use auto in function declaration"  actually yes in C++20.